# solve $\log _{0.5}x$ = $0.5^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you solve the above equation?

Looking at a graphing calculator it states that x is approximately equal to 0.64

If you remove the logs it still does not help - it makes the equation more complicated

Comment: "How would you solve the above equation?" With a calculator.

Comment: It would be easier (for me) to think about using base 2 for the log and the power, i.e. $\log_{0.5} x = - \log_2 x$ and $0.5^x = 2^{-x}$.

Comment: Answer via Mathematica NSolve: 0.641186+

Answer (score 1):

As already written, you basically look for the zero of function $$f(x)=2^x\log(x)+\log(2)$$ for which there is no explicit solution. But you noticed that the solution if close to $0.64$.

So let us apply Newton iterative method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For your problem, $$f'(x)=\frac{2^x}{x}+2^x \log (2) \log (x)$$ and now, let us start with $x_0=0.5$ (just to show how it works).

The following iterates are then produced : $0.633604$, $0.641174$, $0.641186$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Just for demonstration, let us start very far away from the solution, say at $x_0=5$. Then, the following iterates are  produced : $3.76017$, $2.59832$, $1.57673$, $0.852695$, $0.641383$, $0.641186$.

Answer (score 0):

your equation is equivalent to $2^x\ln(x)+\ln(2)=0$ by a numerical method we get $x\approx 0.6411857445049859844862004821148236665628209571911017551396987975434874918787997622340536934991685889$

Comment: Is it really necessary to quote it to that many digits?